# pidgin always shows offline "buddies"

Tags: pidgin

I have the latest version of Pidgin installed on Windows, and the "hide when offline" / "show when offline" feature has no effect.  I always see all the offline "buddies".  What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
Buddies -> Show -> [ ] Offline Buddies
```

[image]

Comment: velly cool! it worked! A bit non-intuitive though... there are 2 places you need to set it in order for it to work (as shown above and by right-clicking each buddy group)